# Ubuntu 18.04 broke after restart

Tags: 18.04, logout

This is my screen after restart or logout:

[image]

How to fix that?
This is Ubuntu 18.04 with:

```
Linux niki-desktop 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu 
SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's good that I have a backup image.
This already happened to me three times.

This is status before restart:

[image]

At dmesg:

[image: dmesg command before restart]

I have that Ubuntu long time ago,that problem occurred after I had upgraded the kernel to 5.0

info1:

```
niki@niki-desktop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B150 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240/340]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
niki@niki-desktop:~$
```

Other info:

[image: lshw]

System disk SMART test:

[image: SMART info]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102030/discussion-on-question-by-delphi-niki-my-ubuntu-18-04-lts-broke-after-restart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a read-only file system, probably due to disk problems. You have a lot of CRC errors, as shown in the SMART Data for the drive.

---

Lets first try and `fsck` the SSD and verify the file system...

At the `(initramfs)` try:

`exit`

note which disk partition it calls out.

`fsck -f /dev/sda1`

`reboot`

---

If you can't `fsck` it that way, then here's the sure-fire way to do it...

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

---

We verified that your Samsung SSD is at the correct firmware version of EMT02B6Q.

---

Since this is not the first time this has occurred, we should check a few other things...

- Check the SATA data and power cables to the Samsung SSD. Disconnect and reconnect the cables at both the SSD end, and at the motherboard. Keep these cables away from power supply wires. We're looking to solve an intermittent connection problem.
- We need to check your memory, as memory is used for disk and file buffers, and can cause disk corruption. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.
- Keep monitoring the SMART Data, and particularly the CRC error count. Assure that this count does not continue to increase. If it does, and you've done the prior two items, then your SSD may be failing.
- Since this problem **may** have started after manually updating your kernel to 5.0, you may have to try reverting to an earlier kernel.